# Unable to deploy Talend job web service

Tags: tomcat, deployment, talend

I am trying to deploy a Talend (V5.4.1) job service by following the guide here: https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Deploying+or+exposing+a+job+as+a+Web+service

I am able to generate the .war file and to place the .war file into tomcat/webapp folder, but the "error" shows up when I try to call the web service in the browser:

[image: AXIS engine could not find a target service to invoke!]

"patchSolrIndexUpdate_0.1" is the job I created on Talend, it works fine when I run it manually.

I have also added axis.jar files into my tomcat/lib, but it does not help. Is anyone experienced in the similar behavior? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I got this issue solved. It's really stupid, the url should be localhost:8080/patchSolrIndexUpdate_0.1/services/patchSolrIndexUpdate?method=runJob
instead of 
localhost:8080/patchSolrIndexUpdate_0.1/services/patchSolrIndexUpdate_0.1?method=runJob.

Can't believe this took me a day to figure out that extra string _0.1 ....